# How to share a component library between 2 Angular apps

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have the following folder structure

```
proj-folder
|-app1
|-app2
|-core
```

app1 and app2 folder where created with `ng new app1` command.

I just want to put on corelib folder modules, services and components to share bewteen app1 and app2.**I do not want to make an npm package for my core lib**.

I have already tried many things. The one that almost worked was:
on corelib folder I copied package.json form app1, then `npm install` and then on app1 on the file tsconfig.json change the paths as the following:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["../../core/src/*"],
    }
```

If I do `ng build` on app1 works perfectly. But when I do `ng build --prod` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../../core/core.module.ts(5,2): Error during template compile of 'CoreModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
    'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.
```

How can share a lib can be so complicated? I have read a lot of places but there is not an easy way. What I'm missing?

Comment: can you share the core.module.ts code? its an AOT error.

Comment: @DanielNetzer you can check the code here. But the code is empty, is the basic code generate by ng cli.
https://github.com/elranu/pude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was different version on @angular on the `package.json` and also the following line on the tsconfig.json:

```
"@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"]
```

Check the [PR](https://github.com/elranu/pude/pull/3/files).
More info I have found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-linked-library)

**UPDATE:**
Is important to add on the `tsconfig.json` each library that is imported on the shared lib, on the main app.

Example:

```
  "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
  "rxjs/*" : ["../node_modules/rxjs/*"],
  "firebase/*": ["../node_modules/firebase/*"],
  "angularfire2/*": ["../node_modules/angularfire2/*"]
```

full code: [link](https://github.com/elranu/pude/commit/e07a99239a1bb8247d2c7029067d523de87d057a#diff-4228c7cc2954001b5ab4bc551c6f4c33)

Comment: I don't know who or where you are, but I love you.

Comment: @yellowblood hehehe thanks. It works, but I'm having a lot of issues later. I'm working with Angularfire and Firebase and I'm getting all the times strange errors. That if the same service is in on app I do not get those errors. So be careful with this approach

Comment: I'm having awful issues too, I don't know why Angular is so bad at code structure.. thanks

Comment: Very cool, It worked for me! Also you need to be sure that you have baseUrl and path, into compilerOptions, like here on the github provided in the response: https://github.com/elranu/pude/blob/master/members/tsconfig.json